# Cannot see any applications except the menu bar

Tags: 13.10, display

I'm running 13.10 in a virtual machine using Parallels 9. I recently installed some updates and was prompted to restart. Now cannot see any running application. I am able to see the menu bar on the side but it seems like there is just a black space where I would normally expect to see the application.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhCi2.png - I can't post images so here's the first screen shot

The only thing that opens is the top icon and even it does not display correctly

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C37h.png - Here is the only application which is working

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Shut down VM (13.10), then in Parallels 9 config for the VM, go to >Hardware>Video, and "Un-check" 3D acceleration.

Restart Ubuntu 13.10. You will now get a Completely Black screen. Shut down Ubuntu once more.

Again, in Parallels config for the VM, go to Hardware>Video and "Re-Check" 3D acceleration. Restart, and, Viola, back in business (No black screen and everything properly updated).